# How to search an array for duplicate by using substring

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to filter an array for duplicate values by splitting/substring the elements.

I need to split these data by "-" and search for duplicate string after the "-" and write the element with the duplicate string to the duplicate array.

Here is what I am working on:

```js
  var arr = ['abc-10.10.10.0/22','abc-10.01.21.0/22','abc-10.01.01.0/22','abcd-10.01.01.0/22'];
    var duplicates = [];

arr.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    if (array.indexOf(value, index + 1) !== -1
        && duplicates.indexOf(value) === -1) {
        duplicates.push(value);
    }
});

console.log("Duplicate values:", duplicates); 
//Desired output 'abc-10.01.01.0/22','abcd-10.01.01.0/22'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to use `Array#indexOf` you first would need to use `Array#map` and `String#split` to create a new array of the target sub-strings.

But you can also add an inner loop and use equality to compare the strings as follows:

```js
const arr = ['abc-10.10.10.0/22','abc-10.01.21.0/22','abc-10.01.01.0/22','abcd-10.01.01.0/22'];
const duplicates = [];

arr.forEach(function (value, index, array) {
    array.slice(index+1).forEach(function(val, i) {
        if (value.split('-')[1] === val.split('-')[1]
            && duplicates.indexOf(value.split('-')[1]) === -1) {
            duplicates.push(value);
        }
    });
});

console.log("Duplicate values:", duplicates); 
//Desired output 'abc-10.01.01.0/22','abcd-10.01.01.0/22'
```

Comment: Thank you  PeterKA! I am able to run your code on my JavaScript editor.

Comment: Glad you found this helpful. Enjoy! Feel free to `^` to indicate you found the answer useful.

Answer (score 1):

### Using [Object.groupBy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/groupBy)

Simplest implementation - just group by the substring, and return all results with a count > 1.

```js
function getDuplicates(xs, selector) {
    const group = Object.groupBy(xs, selector);
    return Object.keys(group)
        .filter(k => group[k].length > 1)
        .map(k => group[k])
        .flat();
}

var arr = ['abc-10.10.10.0/22','abc-10.01.21.0/22','abc-10.01.01.0/22','abcd-10.01.01.0/22'];
getDuplicates(arr, (x) => x.split('-')[1])
```

### Custom Implementation

In this case, you are trying to solve for a unique on the selector, but keep the original values. With this, we need to keep track both of the duplicate substrings, and what substrings link to the original value.

This implementation is tightly solved for this problem, and the only benefit is not needing to filter before selecting the values at the cost of an additional set. I don't think this is worth the possible slight performance gain (code is harder to maintain / less easy to understand, increased space complexity), but I've provided it nonetheless.

```js
function getDuplicates(xs, selector) {
    const selectSet = new Set(); // list of all duplicate found selectors
    const selectToXs = {}; // key of selector to return original values
    for(const x of xs) {
        const sub = selector(x);
        if (sub in selectToXs) {
            selectSet.add(sub);
            selectToXs[sub].add(x);
        } else {
            selectToXs[sub] = new Set([x]);
        }
    }
    return [...selectSet].map((s) => [...selectToXs[s]]).flat();
}

var arr = ['abc-10.10.10.0/22','abc-10.01.21.0/22','abc-10.01.01.0/22','abcd-10.01.01.0/22'];
getDuplicates(arr, (x) => x.split('-')[1])
```

Comment: Thank you so much for looking into this. The javascript editor i am using does not recognize Arrow Function "=>".  Bui thanks for tips, I will see if i can convert this into the regular javascript function:)

Comment: It is pretty easy to convert arrow to regular js functions! just swap `() => 1` with `function() { return 1; }`.

Comment: @user1774445 sounds like your JavaScript editor is nearly 10 years old. Anonymous (arrow, lambda, ect) functions are used fairly often now a days.

Comment: Agree. This is a vendor owned application javascript editor which i have no control over. But I am trying to get around it:)

Comment: Also, it does not support new Set(), so i have to find an alternative command for preforming same task.

Answer (score 0):

probably not optimal:

```js
const arr = ['abc-10.10.10.0/22','abc-10.01.21.0/22','abc-10.01.01.0/22','abcd-10.01.01.0/22'];


const afterSet = new Set();
const duplicateSet = new Set();
arr.forEach(function(str){
  const afterString = str.split('-').at(1);
  if(afterString !== undefined &&
     afterSet.size === afterSet.add(afterString).size){
      duplicateSet.add(afterString);
     }
});
const duplicates = arr.filter(
  function(str){
    return duplicateSet.has(str.split('-').at(1))
  }
);

console.log("Duplicate values:", duplicates); 
//Desired output 'abc-10.01.01.0/22','abcd-10.01.01.0/22'
```

Comment: Thanks for looking this for me Bobby! The javascript editor i am using does not recognize Arrow Function "=>".  Bui thanks for the tips, I will see if i can convert this into the regular javascript function:)

Comment: I've updated it to only use function functions

Answer (score 0):

A very old-school way to do this would be to group the items by a key, and then reduce the values into a single array.

```js
var arr = [
  'abc-10.10.10.0/22',
  'abc-10.01.21.0/22',
  'abc-10.01.01.0/22', // Duplicate
  'abcd-10.01.01.0/22' // Duplicate
];

var groups = arr.reduce(function(groups, value, index, array) {
  var tokens = value.split('-');
  var key = tokens.length > 0 ? tokens[1] : value;
  if (groups[key] === undefined) {
    groups[key] = [];
  }
  groups[key].push(value);
  return groups;
}, {});

var duplicates = Object.values(groups)
  .reduce(function(duplicates, values) {
    if (values.length > 1) {
      return duplicates.concat(values);
    }
    return duplicates;
  }, []);


// Expected: abc-10.01.01.0/22 abcd-10.01.01.0/22
console.log("Duplicate values:", ...duplicates);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

If you want to do this in liner time, you will need a map and a set to keep track of seen and staged respectively.

```js
const arr = [
  'abc-10.10.10.0/22',
  'abc-10.01.21.0/22',
  'abc-10.01.01.0/22', // Duplicate
  'abcd-10.01.01.0/22' // Duplicate
];

const duplicates = findDuplicates(arr, (v) => v.split('-').pop());

// Expected: abc-10.01.01.0/22 abcd-10.01.01.0/22
console.log('Duplicates:', ...duplicates);

function findDuplicates(arr, keyFn) {
  const result = [];
  const seen = new Set();
  const staged = new Map();
  for (let item of arr) {
    const key = keyFn?.(item) ?? item;
    if (!seen.has(key)) {
      seen.add(key);
      staged.set(key, item);
    } else {
      if (staged.has(key)) {
        result.push(staged.get(key));
        staged.delete(key);
      }
      result.push(item);
    }
  }
  console.log('Unique: ', ...[...staged.values()]); // DEBUG!
  return result;
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```